# Seperate augmented file in typescript

Tags: typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

Iam using material ui with typescript and i have to declare the Theme interface and  ThemeOptions but it works only if it is in the same file. Is there a better way to distinguish the declarations from the actual tsx file?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { orange } from "@mui/material/colors";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    status: {
      danger: string;
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    status?: {
      danger?: string;
    };
  }
}
const theme = createTheme({
  status: {
    danger: orange[500],
  },
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Move it to a global ambient type declaration file

Comment: Im new to typescript. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your desired directory inside your project and create a `[name].d.ts` file (name as you prefer). Inside something like:

```
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material/styles"; // I strongly recommend use this path. 
import { Theme } from "@mui/material/styles"; // I strongly recommend use this path. 

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    status: {
      danger: string;
    };
  }
  interface ThemeOptions {
    status?: {
      danger?: string;
    };
  }
}
```

After that you don't have to import the file anywhere, TS project adds automatically the new properties to `Theme` and `ThemeOptions`

Remember that the `ThemeOptions` is to use the `createTheme` function and the `Theme` is to use the `useTheme` or `makeStyles` function, both of those file should (preferable) have the same properties (all optional in the `Theme` one)